# const char* changing it vallues when inside parallel region

Tags: c++, openmp

I have the following C++ code using OpenMP

```
int number_of_frames = 200;

stringstream ss_n_frames;
ss_n_frames << number_of_frames;
const char *argv_visual[] = { "program_name" , ss_n_frames.str().c_str() };
std::cout << "\nargv[0] = "<<argv_visual[0];
std::cout << "\nargv[1] = "<<argv_visual[1];

#pragma omp parallel sections shared(number_of_frames)
{
     #pragma omp section
     {
        std::cout << "\n[Parallel region] argv[0] = "<<argv_visual[0];
        std::cout << "\n[Parallel region] argv[1] = "<<argv_visual[1];
     }

     #pragma omp section
     {
        // doing things that has nothing to do with argv_visual
     }
}
```

And here is what i see in the terminal

```
argv[0] = program_name
argv[1] = 200
[Parallel region] argv[0] = program_name
[Parallel region] argv[1] = !
```

So the value of "argv_visual[1]" has changed inside the paralle region, anyone know why?

**EDIT**

Fixed in the following way:

```
stringstream ss_n_frames;
ss_n_frames << number_of_frames;
string string_n_frames = ss_n_frames.str();
const char *constchar_n_frames = string_n_frames.c_str();

const char *argv_visual[] = { "program_name" , constchar_n_frames };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
ss_n_frames.str().c_str()
```

You are getting the pointer to the contents of a temporary string which is destroyed at the end of the statement (at latest) and then trying to read the memory afterwards which is undefined behavior. To fix this, create a non-temporary copy of `ss_n_frames.str()` and print that instead.

If we want to speculate, the reason it doesn't print the string anyway (since a `string` allocates its memory on the free-store and you wouldn't expect the same free-store location to be used again so quickly, since you don't do any other dynamic allocations) is probably due to the short-string optimization.